Implementing Cross-Iframe Communication in Open-Source Appsmith Using postMessage
I am using the open-source version of Appsmith and have two separate Appsmith apps (App1 and App2) embedded on the same HTML page using iframes. I would like these apps to communicate with each other by exchanging data or triggering actions.
Since Appsmith’s documentation indicates that messaging integrations are only available in the Enterprise version, I’m exploring whether I can implement cross-iframe messaging in the open-source version by modifying the codebase.
Main Question:
Has anyone successfully used postMessage or another method for cross-iframe communication with the open-source Appsmith? If so, could you provide guidance on which parts of the Appsmith codebase to focus on to achieve this?
Any technical pointers or examples on implementing postMessage for this purpose would be very helpful. Thank you!
